# Scrollview and image dragging issue

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that has a number of custom imageviews in it.  I use the custom imageviews as I need to be able to drag any one of them off the scrollview and to another location on the iPad screen, bit like a photo picker.

Problem is if I want to scroll the scroll view most of the time the custom imageview gets the touch and moves rather than the desired scroll?

I notice in the sample code from Apple using the autoscroll example that they have the same issue but they have left a large gap between the images....ugly!

Is there a way to let the app know when you want the touch to be a scroll and when to be a drag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make a drag require holding for 1 second, similar to the behavior of the home screen when in editing mode: if you want to scroll, you just flick; if you want to drag, hold down for a moment until the icon enlarges, then you can move it.

Comment: Oooo that sounds like a doer!